# Compare Array of IDs Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a simple scenario for which i want to write LINQ query, But i am unable to get it right. Here is the scenario:

I have 3 Tables:

```
STUDENT:
    --------------------------
    SID   Name
    ---------------------
    1     Jhon
    2     Mishi
    3     Cook
    4     Steven

COURSE:
    -------------------
    CID     Name
    -------------------
    1       Maths
    2       Physics
    3       Bio
    4       CS

STUDENTCOURSE:
    ---------------------------
    SCID   SID   CID
    -----------------------
    1       1     1
    2       1     2
    3       1     4
    4       2     1
    5       2     2
    6       2     3
    7       3     1
    8       3     4
    10      4     2
```

For this case i want to pass array of course ids to query and return all student those have all the these courses registered against them. What i tried:

```
 int[] cIds = {1,2,4 };
 var result = from s in context.Students
              where s.StudentCourses.Any(sc=> cIds.Contains(sc.CID))
              select s;
```

But this returns students those registered either of the course id 1,2,4.
Hope you understand my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current query gives you results for any student that has registered for courses 1 OR 2 OR 4.  You would prefer to have results for students that have registered for all three courses?

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to come up with the statement (I could do it easily in SQL, but my linq grouping is rusty). Select the SIDs from StudentCourse by grouping by SID, counting CID where in cIds, and having the count equal to the length of cIds.

Comment: @AndyNichols: sounds like a better solution than mine. :)  Good job.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy I think my comment still stands. The "counting CID where in cIds" part means that any courses not in the cIds will be ignored.

Comment: @AndyNichols, Yeh, you are right, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
int[] cIds = {1,2,4 };
var q = context.StudentCourses.Join(context.Students, 
                                    x => x.SId, 
                                    x => x.Id, 
                                    (sc, s) => new { Student = s, CourseId = sc.CId })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Student.Id)
        .Where(sc => cIds.All(cid => sc.Any(y => y.CourseId == cid)))
        .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().Student)
        .ToList();
```

Or if you prefer linq query:

```
int[] cIds = {1,2,4 };
var q2 = (from s in context.Students
          join sc in context.StudentCourses on s.Id equals sc.SId into sCources
          where cIds.All(id => sCources.Any(y => y.CId == id))
          select s).ToList();
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TFBqfU) for it, using linq-to-objects.

**Edit:**
I didn't notice that in your model there is a navigation property from `Student` to `StudentCourse`, in this case the query will be much simpler and does not need join, and [Patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983778/compare-array-of-ids-entity-framework/31984609#31985950) answer works perfectly.

Comment: Appreciated. but i didnt give it a try. Let me give it a try in while then i will give a feedback on it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
int[] cIds = {1,2,4 };
var result = from s in context.Students
             where cIds.All(id => s.StudentCourses.Any(sc=> sc.CID == id))
             select s;
```

Comment: It works perfectly if your model has either a navigation from Student to Course entity (navigate from Student to Courses instead of Student to StudentCourses) or a navigation from Student to StudentCourse with foreign keys included. Regarding your code, I assumed the last one.

Comment: forgien key relation exists between student and studentcourses. so there is no issue with s.StudentCourses . but when i try it . it returns 0 results

Comment: I receive 1 result (student "Jhon"). Did you exactly copy my where clause into your code? And is the array generated (if it's not hard coded) before executing the query?